# How to set colorcolumn / cc to the cursor column?

Tags: vim

Is there an easy way to set the `colorcolumn` to the column the cursor is at?

Currently I am doing:

1. Manually note the column in the status bar or using `CTRL+g` (e.g., column 12)
2. Set the colorcolumn to that position (e.g., `:set colorcolumn=12`)

`:help colorcolumn`

Comment: So you want `colorcolumn` to be set once to the current cursor column but not follow cursor until reset next time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current column calling function [`col('.')`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#col()).

To set the result of the call to an option you need to construct an expression and [`execute`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:execute) it. This way:

```
:exe 'set cc=' . col('.')
```

First this calls the function obtaining the current cursor column; let's say the result is `12`. Then a string expression is constructed: `'set cc=' . 12` (where `.` is string concatenation operator in VimScript; the numeric value is converted to string automatically) giving a string `set cc=12`. Last, the expression is executed as if you entered it in the command line.

The result is a bit long so if you gonna use it frequently you better write a command/function for it and save the command/function in your `~/.vimrc` or `~/.vim/`.

```
function! SetCChere()
    :execute 'set colorcolumn=' . col('.')
endfunction

command! SetCChere call SetCChere()
```

Now execute `:SetCChere` — and voila!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an easy way to highlight the column of the cursor.

`:set cursorcolumn`

Comment: That's pretty nice, but not what I'm looking for.  `cursorcolumn` highlights the column that the cursor is in, and moves with the cursor.  I'm looking to set a `colorcolumn` (set to the current position of the cursor) which remains static regardless of where the cursor moves to.